# jquery checkbox listener for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

**SOLUTION**

https://github.com/Campos696/Attendance/commit/28177ff5cf285e9616faddae74fa6f0288a8667a

i have this javascript file:

https://github.com/Campos696/Attendance/blob/master/js/app.js

and am trying to make it so that the checkboxes created by the bodyView, have click listeners, however right now i can only create a listener for one checkbox at a time,  is there any way to improve this?

And whether i check or uncheck it does the same thing(decreases daysMissed).

Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
var bodyView = {

  init: function() {
    this.render();
  },

  render: function() {
    var student, i, x;

    var schoolDays = octopus.getSchoolDays();
    var students = octopus.getStudents();


    for(i = 0;i < students.length; i++) {
      octopus.setCurrentStudent(students[i]);
      var daysMissed = octopus.getDaysMissed();
      $('#students').append('<tr class="'+i+'"><td class="name-col">' + students[i].name + '</td></tr>');
      for(x = 1;x < schoolDays; x++) {
        $('.'+i).append('<td id="check'+i+'" class="attend-col"><input type="checkbox"></td>');
      };
      $('.'+i).append('<td class="missed-col">'+ daysMissed + '</td>');
    };
    $(function(){
      $('#check0').click(function() {
        octopus.setCurrentStudent(students[0]);
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
          octopus.incrementDaysMissed();
        } else if(!$(this).is(':checked')){
          octopus.decreaseDaysMissed();
        }
      })
    })
  }
}
```

**FUNCTION EDIT**

```
$(function(){
         $('[id^=check] :checkbox').on('change', function(e) {                
            var daysMissed = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:last');

            if (this.checked) {
              octopus.decreaseDaysMissed();
              daysMissed.html(octopus.getDaysMissed());
            } else {
              octopus.incrementDaysMissed();
              daysMissed.html(octopus.getDaysMissed());
            }
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDs must be unique. That means you need to change the following line:

```
$('.'+i).append('<td id="check'+i+'" class="attend-col"><input type="checkbox"></td>');
```

with:

```
$('.'+i).append('<td id="check'+ i + x +'" class="attend-col"><input type="checkbox"></td>');
                               ^^^^^^^^
```

In this way each td has an id like: check01.....check46...

Second issue: change the click event with the change event and attach it to:

```
$('[id^=check] :checkbox').on('change', function(e) {
```

select each **td** having an **id** starting with **check** and for each td get the  child checkbox.

```js
var model = {

    currentStudent: null,
    schoolDays: 12,
    students: [
        {
            name: "Slappy the Frog",
            daysMissed: 12
        },
        {
            name: "Lilly the Lizard",
            daysMissed: 12
        },
        {
            name: "Paulrus the Walrus",
            daysMissed: 12
        },
        {
            name: "Gregory the Goat",
            daysMissed: 12
        },
        {
            name: "Adam the Anaconda",
            daysMissed: 12
        }
    ]
};

// Octopus

var octopus = {

    init: function () {
        model.currentStudent = model.students[0];
        headerView.init();
        bodyView.init();
    },

    getStudents: function () {
        return model.students;
    },

    setCurrentStudent: function (student) {
        model.currentStudent = student;
    },

    getSchoolDays: function () {
        return model.schoolDays + 1;
    },

    getDaysMissed: function () {
        return model.currentStudent.daysMissed;
    },

    incrementDaysMissed: function () {
        model.currentStudent.daysMissed++;
    },

    decreaseDaysMissed: function () {
        model.currentStudent.daysMissed--;
    }
};

// View

var headerView = {

    init: function () {
        this.render();
    },

    render: function () {
        var i;

        var schoolDays = octopus.getSchoolDays();

        $('#header').append('<th class="name-col">Student Name</th>');
        for (i = 1; i < schoolDays; i++) {
            $('#header').append('<th>' + i + '</th>');
        }
        ;
        $('#header').append('<th class="missed-col">Days Missed</th>');
    }
};

var bodyView = {

    init: function () {
        this.render();
    },

    render: function () {
        var student, i, x;

        var schoolDays = octopus.getSchoolDays();
        var students = octopus.getStudents();


        $('#students').empty();
        for (i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
            octopus.setCurrentStudent(students[i]);
            var daysMissed = octopus.getDaysMissed();
            $('#students').append('<tr class="' + i + '"><td class="name-col">' + students[i].name + '</td></tr>');
            for (x = 1; x < schoolDays; x++) {
                $('.' + i).append('<td id="check' + i + x + '" class="attend-col"><input type="checkbox"></td>');
            }
            $('.' + i).append('<td class="missed-col">' + daysMissed + '</td>');
        }
        $(function(){
            $('[id^=check] :checkbox').on('change', function(e) {
                var colId = $(this).closest('td').index();
                var rowId = $(this).closest('tr').index();
                var studentName =
                        $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text();

                console.log('Student: <' + studentName +
                        '> on day: ' + colId + ' changed to: ' +
                        this.checked + ' Col: ' + colId + ' Row: ' + rowId);
            })
        })
    }
}
$(function () {
    octopus.init();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/Campos696/Attendance/master/css/style.css">

<h1>Udacity Attendance</h1>

<table>
    <thead>
    <tr id="header"></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="students"></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Is there any way to separate the checkboxes by their first number, say i have the check0* boxes and the check1* boxes,i want an if statement that only happens when i click the check0* boxes but not the check1* boxes, because since i have multiple students and each checkbox row belongs to one of them, i tried putting the function inside the for loop for students length, and using `$('[id^=check'+i+'] :checkbox')` but it didnt work

Comment: It works mostly perfectly the only problem is that i set it so that when i click the checkbox it updates days missed and if i click checkboxes on two different rows it remembers the previous one, for instance i have 12 days missed in row 1 if i click any checkbox in row 1 it goes to 11 days missed, however if i then click a checkbox on another row the days missed in that row go down to 10 instead of 11. I have Updated the github repo if you need to see the changes

Comment: I use it to determine the daysMissed, however the bug still stands, i dont really understand why, i will edit my question with the function i created so as to have better formatting

Comment: Before decrease you need to set current student. I assume that is the direction to look for...

Answer (score 0):

Use the input:checkbox selector to get all checkboxes:

```
$(function(){
  $("input:checkbox").click(function() {
    octopus.setCurrentStudent(students[0]);
    if($(this).prop("checked",true)){
      octopus.incrementDaysMissed();
    } else {
      octopus.decreaseDaysMissed();
    }
  });
});
```